# Google Compute Engine time zone

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, rhel7

I was wondering why my google compute engine virtual machine (Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7) located in the us-central1-a zone uses the Greenwich time zone. NTP server does not work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation [CHAPTER 3. CONFIGURING THE DATE AND TIME](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/chap-configuring_the_date_and_time):

> By default, the system is configured to use UTC.

and accordinly to [Coordinated Universal Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time):

> Coordinated Universal Time (or UTC) is the primary time standard by
>   which the world regulates clocks and time. It is within about 1 second
>   of mean solar time at 0° longitude, and is not adjusted for daylight
>   saving time. It is effectively a successor to Greenwich Mean Time
>   (GMT).

I've created test VM at `us-central1-a` and checked time and [NTP status](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/s1-checking_the_status_of_ntp):

```
$ timedatectl 
      Local time: Mon 2020-05-11 08:50:18 UTC
  Universal time: Mon 2020-05-11 08:50:18 UTC
        RTC time: Mon 2020-05-11 08:50:18
       Time zone: UTC (UTC, +0000)
     NTP enabled: yes
NTP synchronized: yes
 RTC in local TZ: no
      DST active: n/a

$ ntpstat
synchronised to NTP server (169.254.169.254) at stratum 3
   time correct to within 1 ms
   polling server every 64 s
```

everything looks like expected. In addition, I've checked at VMs in other zones and found same default settings.

You're able to change time zone by following instructions [3.1.4. Changing the Time Zone](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/chap-configuring_the_date_and_time):

> To list all available time zones, type the following at a shell
>   prompt:
>
> ```
> timedatectl list-timezones
> ```
>
> To change the currently used time zone, type as root:
>
> ```
> timedatectl set-timezone time_zone
> ```
>
> Replace time_zone with any of the values listed by the timedatectl
>   list-timezones command.